# show description of an unambiguous completion suggestion

Tags: zsh

zsh completion functions, such as `_describe` or `_arguments` can add descriptions to their suggestions:

```bsh
prompt% function _myfun() {thingstodo=('one:do one thing' 'nope:do nothing'); _describe 'possible things to do' thingstodo}
prompt% compdef _myfun myfun
prompt% myfun⇥
things to do:
nothing -- do nothing
one     -- do one thing
```

In case the completion is unambiguous, these descriptions are not shown, instead the only possible completion is inserted

```bsh
prompt% myfun o⇥
```

results in

```bsh
prompt% myfun one
```

(a space is inserted after `one` and the cursor is at the end of the line).

Is there a way - as a user triggering the completion - to see the description anyway? E.g. for the case where I'm wondering "that one and only option, what is it doing again?" So I don't really want to manipulate the completion function itself, but rather have something globally. I imagine this could be a zle widget to trigger manually (possibly with moving the cursor to a different place or deleting the suggestion again if needed). Or maybe a zstyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `list-choices` widget. By default this is bound to Ctrl-D (vi mode) and Meta-Ctrl-D (emacs mode).

Oliver